# Why this variable is type 'String?' even when any null check was removed?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

I want to store a token with the dart package shared_preferences(just for testing purposes), and dart retrofit to make the http requets, but when using _testToken.setString(key, token), dart pops an error at the token (_testToken.setString(key, **token**)): **The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'**, I removed any null safe from the retrofit token response looking for a solution but I am getting the same error, and besides that dart is showing another error saying that I should add null safe to the token response which will give an error if I use it to store shared_preferences.

Here the retrofit Response file:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ResponseData {

  @JsonKey(name: 'status')
  final int? statusCode;

  Map<String, String> data;

  ResponseData({this.data, this.statusCode}); // Here I had required on data and removed it

  factory ResponseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ResponseDataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ResponseDataToJson(this);

}
```

Main Retrofit http file:

```
part 'rest_api_service.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "http://192.168.1.120/api/mobile")
abstract class RestClient {

  factory RestClient(Dio dio, {String? baseUrl}) = _RestClient;

  @Headers(<String, dynamic> {
    "Cache-Control" : "max-age=0",
    "Data-Agent" : "EMMappV2",
    "content-type" : "multipart/form-data",
    "accept" : "application/json"
  })

  @POST("/login")
  Future<ResponseData> loginUser( // here using the ResponseData
      @Field("email") String email,
      @Field("password") String password,
      @Field("device_name") String deviceName
      );

}
```

AuthProvider file (only showing the function):

```
  await client.loginUser(email, password, deviceName).then(
          (value) => {
            print(value.data["token"]),
            variabl = value.data["token"],
            // _storage.write(key: "token", value: value.data["token"]),  Does not work on web version
            _testToken.setString('token', value.data["token"]), // here the call with the error

            if (value.statusCode == 200 ) {
              RouteKey.navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(loginRoute)
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Dart static analysis can't know for sure that you have a valid `"token"` key inside the `value.data` map with a non-nullable value `value.data["token"]`

A workaround is to use the `!` bang operator to mark this value as non-nullable.

```
_testToken.setString('token', value.data["token"]!),
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Map index operator is nullable
>
> This isn’t really a change, but more a thing to know. The index []
> operator on the Map class returns null if the key isn’t present. This
> implies that the return type of that operator must be nullable: V?
> instead of V

This is because `data['value']` is not guaranted to actually return a value from the map (the key could not exist, and because of Map/HashMap interface, throwing is not a good option) so even if you know all values are not null you don't know what keys will return a not null value at runtime.

Check operators in [Map class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-core/Map-class.html)

If you really want to check your data is not nullable and treat it as that your model should have decode all keys as non nullable parameters

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ResponseData {

  @JsonKey(name: 'status')
  final int? statusCode;

  final String token;
  //final String userName; //and other stuff inside your map

  ResponseData({this.token, this.userName, this.statusCode}); // Here I had required on data and removed it

  factory ResponseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ResponseDataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ResponseDataToJson(this);

}
```

Now your Response data will actually holds all parameters as not null and Dart will not check it for you (unless the map actually doesn't have those values, then fromJson will throw and you will get why Map is actually not a recommendable way to check for not null)

Comment: Thank your explanation, now I understand what was the problem in detail.